# Rails external links with referral

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i've external links in my app, here is the code i'm using :

```
<a href="<%= @game.game_external_link %>" target="_blank">
```

... and when an user clic on it, he goes to https://www.externalsite.com.

I would like to add a referral part for each external link, like this:

https://www.externalsite.com?ref=mywebsite

Could you help?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

For example you can create simple helper, like this:

**application_helper.rb**

```
def self.ref_link(url)
  "#{url}?ref=mywebsite"
end
```

**For views:**

```
<%= link_to 'Label', ApplicationHelper.ref_link(@game.game_external_link), target: '_blank' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use helper method:

```
def build_some_link(page, ref)
    link = "#{page}?#{ref}"
    link_to(link, link, target: '_blank')
end
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be `?` instead of `/`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply adding a helper method like this

```
def url_with_protocol(url, ref)
    /^http/.match(url) ? url : "http://#{url}?ref=#{ref}"
end
```

and call out like this

```
<%= link_to(url_with_protocol(@game.game_external_link, "mywebsite"), target: "_blank") do %>
    External Site
<% end %>
```

Generated HTML like this

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.externalsite.com?ref=mywebsite">
    External Site
</a>
```

Comment: @HenriCHEVALLIER Lets try this